# Enable serving assets in Sails App after using --no-frontend

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'd created a sails 1.0 app with --no-frontend option. Now I want to serve static html from it. Anyway I can rewire it inside the same app.
Where do the settings reside to enable it.